# Parsing Dates using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, json.net

I am using JSON.NET's LINQ to JSON to parse data, which includes dates.  My sample JSON looks like this:

```
{"2013" : [
    { "date":"2/5/2013 11:13 AM","id":23 }],
"2012" : [
    { "date":"28/9/2012 5:29 PM","id":24 }]
}
```

The format of the date is in d/m/yyyy h:mm.  I tried parsing it first using DateTime.Parse:

```
var postTitles = jobject.Children().SelectMany(x => x.First).
    Select(p =>
    new Report
        {
            Date = DateTime.Parse((string)p["date"]),
            Height = (int)p["height"]
        });
```

However, it throws a FormatException on the second date so I tried using DateTime.ParseExact instead:

```
var postTitles = jobject.Children().SelectMany(x => x.First).
    Select(p =>
    new Report
        {
            Date = DateTime.ParseExact(p["date"].ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm", new
                CultureInfo("en-US")),
            Height = (int)p["height"]
        });
```

This time, I get a FormatException on the first date.  Are there any alternatives on how to parse this dates?  I tried using Extension Methods as I am used to doing XML but it seems my extension methods are not recognized.

Answer (score 4):

Your format string for `ParseExact` is very broken. Basically, you really need to pay attention to the format of your actual data, and look at the [MSDN documentation for custom date/time strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). You can't just put any old pattern in and expect it to work: it's got to match your data.

So you probably want a format string of "d/M/yyyy h:mm tt". I would also suggest using the invariant culture:

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact(p["date"].ToString(), "d/M/yyyy h:mm tt",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(The invariant culture is mostly the same as the US culture, but the important aspect is that it indicates that this is intended for machine-generated data rather than genuinely US-centric data.)

There may well be a better way of doing this in JSON.NET, but that should at least be a starting point.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me with regards to format string?  I'm quite confused as the sample usage in the MSDN documentation are for ToString.

Comment: @CCCC: It's hard to give you any further enlightenment without knowing where your confusion is.

Comment: From what I understand, the format specifiers extract specific parts of the date like month, day, and year, which would require a properly formatted date.  The thing that I am trying to do is convert the data found in the JSON file to a properly formatted date.

Comment: @CCCC: The format specifiers basically describe the format of your data. I've only just noticed an earlier edit removed the sample format - I've reinstated that part, but really you should look carefully through the documentation, and look at the format you were providing vs the format which your data is actually in... they're *very* different.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I pasted the wrong snippet as I was trying to work on other data to test if there was something wrong with my formatting.  Corrected it as what I used originally.

Comment: @CCCC: That still doesn't exactly match though, does it? Note that the format string in the accepted answer isn't quite right either, I suspect, due to only having one `m` instead of two.